# Opnet open animation viewer

Tags: opnet

Hi I am trying to use animation feature in opnet. For that I set the preferences to open animation viewer when the simulation starts. During the animation I am trying to call op_anim_viewer_open which always returns -2. No more subsequent GUI call has any effect. I also do not really know what name should i put into viewer id paramaeter of the call. Especially when animation is only stored in file for later usage. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erasing all temporary files in user home resolved the problem.